modify windwos iso. Grampa, acetoniso and iso master not working
Before i go off ranting i'm just gonna ask the question. Is it possible to edit a windows udf iso.
I've tried isomaster, Acetoneiso. The furthest I've gotten is engrampa but that only opens the image in read only mode.
I have downloded udftools and I've tried ark but none of them bar engrampa support udf.
i even tried downloading and installing poweriso for linux but the poweriso.sh file just tells me
"./poweriso.sh: line 3: 76952 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./poweriso
"
and poweriso returns this error
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
I'd like some help guys.
I had a look at he poseriso.sh file
"                                      poweriso.sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=.
./poweriso
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
"
I tried modding the path line but no joy.
HI JayCravens... again!! Thanks for getting back to be so fast. I did everything you suggested and it finally packed the iso for me. but for some reason when i try to boot using the iso file in VirtualBox i have a problem. Firstly the boot menus shows *Windows, then when i press enter it just says "Grub" on screen and that's as far as i can get.. I tested the file by running isoinfo -d -i win82.iso. I got the following: " root@yikes-a320ms2h:/home/yikes/Downloads/win64# isoinfo -d -i win82.iso
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id:
Volume id: ISOIMAGE
Volume set id:
Publisher id:
Data preparer id: XORRISO-1.5.6 2023.06.07.180001, LIBISOBURN-1.5.6, LIBISOFS-1.5.6, LIBBURN-1.5.6
Application id:
Copyright File id:
Abstract File id:
Bibliographic File id:
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 2155895
El Torito VD version 1 found, boot catalog is in sector 3225
NO Joliet present
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found
Eltorito validation header:
Hid 1
Arch 0 (x86)
ID ''
Key 55 AA
Eltorito defaultboot header:
Bootid 88 (bootable)
Boot media 0 (No Emulation Boot)
Load segment 0
Sys type 0
Nsect 4
Bootoff 323A 12858
.i also ran file win82.iso and i got this: "win82.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data (DOS/MBR boot sector) 'ISOIMAGE' (bootable)
" I'm no expert but correct me if I'm wrong but they both indicate that the iso is bootable.
Hi Jay apologies for the late reply i was in hospital for a few days. Well I'm back at the keyboard now. I've tried everything you suggested but i'm still not having any luck booting from a virtual machine. i found the following code "yikes@yikes-a320ms2h:~/Desktop/iso_contents$ sudo su
[sudo] password for yikes:
root@yikes-a320ms2h:/home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents# mkisofs -o new_bootable.iso 
-b boot.img 
-c boot.catalog 
-no-emul-boot 
-boot-load-size 4 
-boot-info-table 
-V "ISO_LABEL" 
-J -R 
home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents/
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
genisoimage: No such file or directory. Invalid node - 'home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents/'.
root@yikes-a320ms2h:/home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents# mkisofs -o new_bootable.iso -b boot.img -c boot.catalog -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -V "ISO_LABEL" -J -R /home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents/
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
File /home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents/sources/install.wim is larger than 4GiB-1.
-allow-limited-size was not specified. There is no way do represent this file size. Aborting.
root@yikes-a320ms2h:/home/yikes/Desktop/iso_contents#
"should i just give up?

Have you tried answers like this one and if so, what was the result?

see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313254/576943

@TheYikes: This answer is well researched. You should accept it. There is a "check" icon besides that answer. Click it.

Make directories & mount the ISO:
mkdir ~/win-iso-mnt ~/win-iso
sudo mount -o loop windows.iso ~/win-iso-mnt

Copy ISO contents:
 cp -r ~/win-iso-mnt ~/win-iso/

Perform task.
Re-create the .iso:
cd ~/win-iso
mkisofs -o ../modified-windows.iso -b boot/boot.img -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table ~/windows-iso

You should be able to extract the boot/boot.img from the original ISO.

Using grub instead, in case you don't have the boot.img file.  This is how to use GRUB to boot.
Make sure you have grub-pc-bin installed:
sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin

Set up a directory for the ISO:
mkdir -p ~/grub-iso/boot/grub

Create a grub.cfg file in the boot/grub directory:
nano ~/grub-iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg

set timeout=5
set default=0

menuentry "Windows" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(cd)
    chainloader +1
}

Copy your Windows files into ~/grub-iso:
cp -r ~/windows-iso/* ~/grub-iso/

Use grub-mkrescue to create the ISO:
grub-mkrescue -o windows.iso ~/grub-iso

If you cannot use the boot/boot.img, this should achieve the same goal.

PLAN C:Create a Bootable ISO with Syslinux.
sudo apt-get install syslinux

Create the directory structure:
mkdir -p ~/syslinux-iso/boot/syslinux

Copy Windows Files:
cp -r ~/windows-iso/* ~/syslinux-iso/

Create Syslinux Configuration File:
nano ~/syslinux-iso/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg

DEFAULT windows
LABEL windows
    MENU LABEL Windows
    COM32 /isolinux/isolinux.bin
    APPEND /bootmgr

Install Syslinux Bootloader:
syslinux -i ~/syslinux-iso/boot/syslinux

Use mkisofs to create the ISO:
mkisofs -o windows-syslinux.iso -b boot/syslinux/isolinux.bin -c boot/syslinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table ~/syslinux-iso

File size issue:
The ISO 9660 filesystem has a limitation of 4gb. You can split the install.wim file into smaller parts using wimlib.
sudo apt-get install wimlib-tools

Use wimlib-imagex to split the install.wim file into smaller files.
This command splits in 3.8gb chunks.
wimlib-imagex split ~/syslinux-iso/sources/install.wim ~/syslinux-iso/sources/install.swm 3800

Now, with the new .swm files in the sources folder of your ISO directory, re-create using mkisofs:
mkisofs -o windows-syslinux.iso -b boot/syslinux/isolinux.bin -c boot/syslinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table ~/syslinux-iso

This is the only way to keep it ISO 9660 compliant. — Never give up, my friend!

Hi JAyCravens. Thanks for answering my question. I tried doing everything as you instructed but after i issue the "sudo mkisofs -o ../modified-windows.iso -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table ." i get this error. "genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'boot/grub/stage2_eltorito' !
"

ok i tried using genisoimage but now i'm getting this. "genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image '/root/win-iso/win-iso-mnt/boot/etfsboot.com' !
"

ok i tried "mkisofs -o /home/yikes/Documents/windwows8iso/modified-windows.iso -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table . now i'm getting this error "genisoimage: No such file or directory. Unable to open disc image file '/home/yikes/Documents/windwows8iso/modified-windows.iso'.
"#

@TheYikes Updated the answer.  Also, here is a github page with a etfsboot.com you could try: https://github.com/schmitmd/Multi-Booter/blob/master/boot/etfsboot.com

HI JayCravens... again!! Thanks for getting back to be so fast. I did everything you suggested and it finally packed the iso for me. but for some reason when i try to boot using the iso file in VirtualBox i have a problem. Firstly the boot menus shows *Windows, then when i press enter it just says "Grub" on screen.

@TheYikes You might need to add a couple lines to the cfg.  I updated the answer.  And make sure you don't use the --no-emul-boot option if you're using VirtualBox.  Might check firmware settings (UEFI vs. BIOS) in VirtualBox also.

i tried plan c but i got this "yikes@yikes-a320ms2h:~$ mkisofs -o windows-syslinux.iso -b boot/syslinux/isolinux.bin -c boot/syslinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table ~/syslinux-iso
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
File /home/yikes/syslinux-iso/sources/install.wim is larger than 4GiB-1.
-allow-limited-size was not specified. There is no way do represent this file size. Aborting.
yikes@yikes-a320ms2h:~$
"

@TheYikes Give that a shot.  Believe it or not, there's yet even more ways!
